# Problem when storing JSX elements inside useState Array of Objects

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change a React component so that I can eventually sort its contents. To that end, I extracted most of the render method into an array of objects, such as

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([        
        {id : 1, item: <div id="SelectionEntryBuildNr">{buildNr}</div> },
        {id : 2, item: <Timestamp id="SelectionEntryTimestamp" relative date={timestamp} /> }
]
```

the `buildNr` and `timestamp` variables are state as well

I then try to render the component

```
<div className={className} onClick={onClick}>
    {items.map(i => i.item)}
</div>
```

and it renders everything correclty, however, where it displayed the data before, it now doesn't seem to display any data (the relative date defaults to "just then"). It seems like it can't correctly access the data.
When I log `items`, I get an Array that contains this:

```
0:
id: 0
item: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
__proto__: Object
```

Why are the JSX elements stored like that? And why can't it access the state variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why JSX is stored like that is because, at the end of the day, JSX is just syntactical sugar for `react.createElement()` syntax, which react will translate into the function with the right parameters to create the appropriate react `element`. check [https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html#:~:text=JSX%20is%20not%20a%20requirement,%2C%20...children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html#:%7E:text=JSX%20is%20not%20a%20requirement,%2C%20...children))%20 to understand this. So in essence, your JSX is being compiled into a react element and stored in that form. In your object that is returned, you can check what value is used for `children` to get a better idea of what is happening to the state variable that is being passed in.

As to understand why this may not be working, it is possible that it is compiling the JSX before state variables have been set, or perhaps it is just not possible to use state variables inside another state variable, or perhaps the variable cannot be found due to scoping issue. Most likely, `undefined` is being passed into the children of the element.

Comment: thanks, seems like I have to improve on my foundational knowledge a bit